# Does Shri Adi Shankaracharya's Advaita say that all Jeevis get liberated at the end of the kalpa?

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya, shankara

I came across [this](https://www.geocities.ws/srigant/rudra-ekadashi.htm) website which claimed,

> At the end of the kalpas, Lord Parameshwara, unites all those souls
> with the Nirguna ParaBhrahman.

**Is this true? Does authentic orthodox view of Shri Adi Shankaracharya say this?**

---

Also [see](https://sthothramala.blogspot.com/2020/12/vivekachoodamani-sri-shankaracharya_7.html):

> The Prakrithi/Prapancha all those material matters and people have
> impermanent nature, undergoes aging, illnesses and death, it is the
> illusion in the Jeeva causes to believe that everything going to
> remain till the Kalpantha, therefore, the eternal truth is that ‘
> Jagath Mithya, Bhrama Sathyam’ and the Paramathma resides as the soul
> is indestructible Purusha

Answer (score 3):

> Does Shri Adi Shankaracharya's Advaita say that all Jeevis get liberated at the end of the kalpa?

**Short answer: No**

**Long answer:**

Adi Shankara talks about two kinds of aspirants for moksha - those who worship saguNa brahman and those who contemplate on nirguNa brahman. The former is upAsana/bhakti mArga, the latter is jnAna mArga.

However, only the jnAni can attain direct moksha (jeevanmukti and videhamukti)  in Shankara siddhAnta. The jnAni is the person who realizes his or her identity with nirguNa brahman.

But what happens to those aspirants who worship saguNa brahman? These aspirants do not get liberation directly, but they attain liberation in stages. This process is called **krama mukti**.

The knowers of saguNa brahman, after death, travel by the path of the Gods (devayAna) until they reach brahmaloka. In brahmaloka, Lord Brahma gives them the knowledge of nirguNa brahman. **At the end of the kalpa, all such jeevas in Brahmaloka (who came there because they knew saguNa brahnan), attain permanent mukti (due to knowledge of nirguNa brahman, granted by the Guru, Lord Brahma Himself).**

[Brahmasutras summary](https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/bs_4/bs_4-2-insy.html)

> In the previous Section it was shown that one attains Jivanmukti when the Sanchita Karmas or the accumulated works which have not as yet begun to bear fruits are destroyed, and Videhamukti at death when the Prarabdha Karma is destroyed.

> This Section is devoted to the mode of departure of the enlightened and the unenlightened souls at the time of leaving the body. The path of the gods, the Devayana, by which the knower of the Saguna Brahman travels after death, is described

[Brahmasutras summary](https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/bs_4/bs_4-4-06.html)

> This Sutra says that these texts refer either to the state of deep sleep or to that of final release in which the soul attains absolute union with the Nirguna Brahman.

> Those passages on the other hand, which describe lordly power refer to an altogether different condition which like the heavenly world, is an abode where knowledge of Saguna Brahman produces its results.

> **We have been discussing in the previous Sutras about one who has not attained absolute union with Nirguna Brahman but only Brahmaloka.** There is cognition in Brahmaloka.

[Brahmasutras summary](https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/bs_4/bs_4-4-07.html)

> **This Sutra refutes this and says that those who go to Brahmaloka by the path of the gods do not return from there.** Because scriptural passages teach that they do not so return. "Going up by that way, one reaches immortality" (Chh. Up. VIII.6.6). "Those who proceed on that path do not return to the life of man" (Chh. Up. IV.15.6). "He reaches the world of Brahman and does not return" (Chh. Up. VII.15.1). "They no more return to this world" (Bri. Up. VI.2.15).

Comment: Also, and this is not an answer because it comes from personal experience, but I've found that one mārga leads to behaviours of the others. For example, by taking the jñāna path and implementing practices (e.g., meditation, mantra, mindfulness, and other things besides reading & study) I became open to bhakti. Not exactly bhakti toward Saguṇa Brahman, but toward all members experiencing māyā. It also makes it easier to "work without expectation of results." 